# Is there a function to add specific numbers across the columns that fall under 2 specific titles?

Tags: sumifs

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72dpb.png)

I want to add all the stocks only under 45 across the columns and sum ifs not working out. Could someone please help me? 45 cells are merged though.

I have tried sumifs with 2 criteria but the answer is either error or not correct. Any help would be much appreciated